# Two classes in same model

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Please let me know;
In OpenERP 7, I created two classes & two tables generated from those classes.finally I called to those classes such as checkroll() and workoffer().now its works perfectly  & thing is want to two tables generated from one class is wrong or correct as per openERP standards.? is there any other way to implement that.?

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class checkroll(osv.osv):
    _name = "checkroll.plucker"
    _description = "This table is for keeping personal data of plucker"
    _columns = {
        'reg_no': fields.char('Registration Number', size=256, required=True),
        'worker_name': fields.char('Worker Name', size=256, required=True),
        'spouse_name': fields.char('Spouse Name', size=256),
        'gender' : fields.selection((('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'), ('middle', 'Test')), 'Gender', required=True),
        'epf_no':fields.char('EPF Number', size=256)
    }

checkroll()



class workoffer(osv.osv):
    _name = "checkroll.work.offer"
    _description = "This table is for keeping work offer data"
    _columns = {
        'date': fields.date("Date"),
        'division': fields.char('Division', size=256, required=True),
        'work' : fields.selection((('plucking', 'Plucking'), ('tapping', 'Tapping'), ('sundry_worker', 'Sundry Worker')), 'Work', required=True),
        'epf_no':fields.char('EPF Number', size=256)
    }

workoffer()
```

Comment: what's the question? title and text say nothing meaningful

Comment: need to know my code under openerp 7 code standards.?
is it may reason for any performance issues.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenERP it is recommended that to define a new model for another database table.
Here each model has one table in database. the table name can be define by model attribute `_table`, if it's not defined it will take from `_name` by default removing .(dot) by _(underscore).